# Attribute.Add on MasterPage <body> tag

Tags: c#, master-pages

I'm attempting to put some javascript into the body tag of my masterpage using the following techinique:

```
<body id="pgBody" runat="server">

//Property to get the body tage in MasterPage.cs
public HtmlGenericControl BodyTag
{
    get
    {
        return this.pgBody; 
    }
}


//In my content page PageLoad()
MasterPage mstrPg = this.Master as MasterPage;
if (mstrPg != null)
{
     mstrPg.BodyTag.Attributes.Add("onload", "LoadMap()");
     mstrPg.BodyTag.Attributes.Add("onunload", "UnloadMap()");
}
```

Everything works as expected when running on my local machine (using the Visual Studio Development Server), but when I deploy it out to a production IIS 6 server the attributes do not get added to the body tag when running the page.

Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: Don't see anything wrong. It should be added.Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

dont know exactly why your code is not working.
and one thing I would recommend using `window.onload` event instead of `body.onload`.

just try following:

**In the Masterpage markup file, put this before closing body tag**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ScriptsPlaceHolder" Visible="false">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () { LoadMap(); };
        window.onunload = function () { UnloadMap(); };
    </script>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**Masterpage codebehind file**

```
public PlaceHolder ScriptsPlaceHolderControl
{
    get { return this.ScriptsPlaceHolder; }
}
```

**In your content page**

```
SiteMaster mstrPg = this.Master as SiteMaster;
if (mstrPg != null)
{
    mstrPg.ScriptsPlaceHolderControl.Visible = true;
}
```